# Button click should add items to array, but array is empty on each function call

Tags: javascript, arrays, shopify, liquid

Code looks something like this

```
let sectionWithLimitItems = [];

function addItems(productId) {
     sectionWithLimitItems.push(productId)
}

<button onclick='appendItems({{ productId }})'>Click Me</button>
```

Working with liquid, Shopify's theme template language, but not sure if that would create complications.
If I log the array each time the function is called, it is empty after at the start of the function and can see the id gets added but the array is empty again on the next button click. Any ideas?

-- Edit - sorry for the mistake everyone! I did have arr.push in my code, not append. Wasn't thinking correctly when I made the post. Still having the same issue with sectionWithLimitItems.push(productId)

Comment: You're looking for [Array.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Comment: My bad, code example was written incorrectly, still not working with arr.push. Thanks for pointing out my mistake

Comment: Then please update your code, and add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

In javascript you don't use `Array.append()`, you should use `Array.push()` ([MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for [`Array.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

```
const sectionWithLimitItems = [];

function appendItems(productId) {
    sectionWithLimitItems.push(productId)
}

<button onclick='appendItems({{ productId }})'>Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

For `Arrays data` structures in Javascript you use the `push()` method to add at the end of the `Array`. For a more detailed explanation check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

```
let sectionWithLimitItems = [];

function appendItems(arr,item) {
  arr.push(item)
}

console.log(sectionWithLimitItems)
```